# receive and process information from the common service between components

Tags: angular, typescript

I have two separate routes. One is products and the other is products-cart. I want to use a common ts file for these two to keep the information of the products and the basket in the form of an array. But i am facing a problem. I can't make any changes or transfers. When I add something to the cart array, the information I pull from the product-cart does not change, it always stays empty. They said that I would resolve this with observable, but I was not successful. what I want is that there will be 3 products and when I add them from localhost:4200/products I can see them in localhost:4200/products/product-cart but these are two separate routes. Note
(urls are for pictures)

**data.service.ts**

```
    import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
    import { Product } from "./product";

    @Injectable()

    export class DataService{

        productsData:Array<Product>=[
        {name:'Tomato',total:10, url:'https://migrostvstr.blob.core.windows.net/migrostv/2021/08/domates-kg-c7462d-1650x1650-1.jpg'},
        {name:'Patato',total:27, url:'https://migros-dali-storage-prod.global.ssl.fastly.net/sanalmarket/product/28303000/patlican-kemer-kg-2ac52c-1650x1650.jpg'},
        {name:'Garlic',total:20, url:'https://migros-dali-storage-prod.global.ssl.fastly.net/sanalmarket/product/28293383/28293383-874ca9-1650x1650.jpg'}
        ];

        


        productscard:Array<Product>=[];

        constructor(){}

    }
```

**products.component.ts**

```
    import { Component, OnInit,Output } from '@angular/core';
import { EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../data.service';
import { Product } from '../product';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-products',
  templateUrl: './products.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./products.component.css']
})
export class ProductsComponent implements OnInit {
    
  constructor(private data:DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    console.log(this.data.productsData)
    
  }

  getItems(value){
    
  }

}
```

**product-cart.components.ts**

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Product} from '../product';
import { DataService } from '../data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-cart',
  templateUrl: './product-cart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-cart.component.css']
})
export class ProductCartComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private datacart:DataService) { }

  ngOnInit (){
    console.log(this.datacart.productscard)
  }

}
```

**products.component.html**

```
<div class="products">
  <div class="product-cards" *ngFor="let items of newData">
    <img class="icons" src="{{items.url}}">
    <div class="items-style">
      <div>
        Ürün ismi: {{items.name}}
      </div>
      <div>
        Ürün adedi: {{items.total}}
      </div>
      <a class="add-icon"><i class="fas fa-cart-plus fa-2x icon"(click)="getItems(items)" ></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see you adding anything to `productscard` array in the DataService. Is this array being populated anywhere? If not, then I think the current behaviour is the expected behaviour

Comment: No we dont adding anything, just think it is.I deleted and rewrote so many code that things got a bit confused

Comment: in your service you need to use BehaviourSubject<Array<Product>>([...data]); then add .next() method in the service and in the component subscribe

Comment: @Tarik you need to add to the `productscard` and then try to access it from the service. I'm not sure what the data flow is, but you can try doing  ` productscard:Array<Product>=['somedata'];` and try to see if you're getting the same thing in your ProductCarts component

Comment: @hous I found answers like you said in my research. But I guess I didn't manage to write them, so I wanted to ask it as a new question.

Comment: @KanishkAnand I can't bring any data to the console even with these codes now

Comment: @Tarik are these part of same app module, or these are separate applications all together? The @Injectable by default uses `root` injector creating an Injector in the ApplicationModule. You may want to use `@Injectable({provideIn: 'platform'})` if they are separate apps.

Comment: @Tarik, check the solution I made, I  hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

All right, make sure you added the service in your module providers (if you have one module it will be the appModule)
in your service add:

```js
//RxJs BehaviorSubject to use initiation value
productsDataEmitter: BehaviorSubject<Array<Product>>
                            =new BehaviorSubject([
                              {name:'Tomato',total:10, url:'https://migrostvstr.blob.core.windows.net/migrostv/2021/08/domates-kg-c7462d-1650x1650-1.jpg'},
                              {name:'Patato',total:27, url:'https://migros-dali-storage-prod.global.ssl.fastly.net/sanalmarket/product/28303000/patlican-kemer-kg-2ac52c-1650x1650.jpg'},
                              {name:'Garlic',total:20, url:'https://migros-dali-storage-prod.global.ssl.fastly.net/sanalmarket/product/28293383/28293383-874ca9-1650x1650.jpg'}
                              ]);

// add this fuction to emit the data:
emitProductsData(products:Array<Product>){
    this.this.productsDataEmitter.next(products);
  }
```

Now in any of your components:

```js
constructor(private data:DataService) { }
// if you want to get the data:
this.data.productsDataEmitter.subscribe(products=>{
console.log('the data array is', products);
});

//if you want to update the data use:
let newData: Array[Product] = [];
this.data.emitProductsData(newData);
```

if you want to read and then update the same subscribed data make sure you do it inside the subscribe scope:

```js
this.data.productsDataEmitter.subscribe(products=>{
console.log('the data array is', products);
let product:Product = new Product();
let newData: Array<Product> = [...products,product];
this.data.emitProductsData(newData);
});
```

Comment: I edit code and add html page.  <div class="product-cards" *ngFor="let items of newData"> what i need to write on in ngFor?

Comment: you mean you want to display the products in a list by an ngFor? by the way please accept the answer if you found it useful @Tarik

Comment: change the <a/> by this `<a href="items.url" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"><i class="fas fa-cart-plus fa-2x icon"></i></a>` (blank is used to open in new tab) and make sure newData has the right data in your ts file

Answer (score 0):

data.service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

export interface Product {
  name: any;
  total: any;
  url: any;
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class DataService {

  productsCart: Product[] = [];
  productsCart$ = new BehaviorSubject<Product[]>([]);

  productsData: Array<Product> = [
    {
      name: 'Tomato',
      total: 10,
      url: '...',
    },
    {
      name: 'Patato',
      total: 27,
      url: '...',
    },
    {
      name: 'Garlic',
      total: 20,
      url: '...',
    },
  ];

  addToCart(product: Product): void {
    this.productsCart.push(product);
    this.productsCart$.next(this.productsCart);
  }
}
```

ProductsComponent:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService, Product } from '../data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-products',
  templateUrl: './products.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./products.component.scss'],
})
export class ProductsComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private service: DataService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.service.productsData);
  }

  addToCart() {
    const product = {
      name: 'Tomato',
      total: 10,
      url: '...',
    };
    this.service.addToCart(product);
  }
}
```

ProductCartComponent:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-cart',
  templateUrl: './product-cart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-cart.component.scss'],
})
export class ProductCartComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private service: DataService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.service.productsCart$.subscribe((data) => {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    });
  }
}
```